# Partial SSL in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

I'm looking to do a partial SSL site in rails. I basically want to protect the user actions behind SSL, but nothing else.

Anyone know of a plugin or gem that makes this simple and efficient?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is typically done with the [SSL Requirement](http://github.com/rails/ssl_requirement/tree/master) plugin. It sets up `before_filter`s allowing you to specify which actions require SSL and which optionally allow it, and which specifically do not allow it.

Outside of that, it's just a matter of setting up 2 VHosts in your Apache (or whichever server you use) configuration, one for the SSL site and one for the non-SSL site.

Comment: Thanks John. I had seen that before, and consider it an option. I'm wondering if there are any other options available.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [ssl_requirement](http://github.com/rails/ssl_requirement/tree/master).  It lets you specify what you want.

Answer (score 1):

[ssl_routes](https://github.com/cedric/ssl_routes) gem defines ssl enforcement rule in the route file. It also will automatically output the url with the correct protocol to prevent redirects.