# Rails SSL only on one specific path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ssl

I'm trying to enable rails SSL on one specific path. The rest of the website should render in http.

Also this connection is made between the rails server and an android device. The android device should send his information in SSL with a own created certificate.

Is this possible in Rails or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Partial SSL in rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795219/partial-ssl-in-rails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [ssl_requirement](https://github.com/bartt/ssl_requirement) gem. It enables specific actions to run under SSL.

Comment: Thanks alot, this seems to do the job :)